# Wildcard DNS setting for another server

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, subdomain, wildcard

My domain is on one server and I wanted to put wildcard DNS settings for another server.

Basically I have two servers and I want all the wildcard to go on second server, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're using Bind, that your server has the ip 1.2.3.4, the other server has the ip 5.6.7.8 and that your main server is named my.domain.com, you just need to add the following lines to your configuration:

```
my.domain.com. 300 IN A 1.2.3.4
*.domain.com. 300 IN A 5.6.7.8
```

If you use tinydns, these are the config lines:

```
=my.domain.com:1.2.3.4:300
=*.mydomain.com:5.6.7.8:300
```

Both configurations will set a 300 seconds TTL to each record.

You can find more info about Wildcard DNS Records [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record).

Hope this helps!

Comment: To improve future performance, once you work out the bugs, you will want to increase the ttl to several hours or longer. A short ttl will mean users of your site will have to perform frequent dns queries to get the proper ip.